# Storing output of a pig script in a file whose filename is dynamically generated

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

While executing the pig script, if you have a step where you store the output into a file. Can we generate the name of the file dynamically without giving a fixed filename.

If it is possible to create the name of the file dynamically, can we keep the current date as the name of the file?

Thanks,

Regards,
Dheeraj Rampally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use parameter substitution either through pig -param date=value or specify date=value in pig.params. You will be able to access the specified value in the pig script through $date